# How do I escape an apostrophe in my variable name within ejs

Tags: node.js, escaping, sails.js, ejs

I have an ejs file in my sails application that looks like this

```
<a href='/<%= viewname %>?where={"name":"<%= profile.pname %>"}'>
```

This works for most of the names with the exception of one that has an apostrophe in it. Essentially EJS parses the apostrophe as a sing quote  which closes the href and makes the name I'm passing incorrect

```
http://localhost:1337/myviewnamwe?where={"name":"tom
```

where it should be

```
http://localhost:1337/myviewnamwe?where={"name":"tom's diner}
```

Comment: Strange--using `<%=` should automatically encode HTML entities in the var. Only `<%-` should return the bare string (with unescaped quotes). What does it look like when you view source on the rendered page?

Answer (score 0):

I would use URL encoding for the critical part: `{"name":"<%= profile.pname %>"}`

More info:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp